# What is the block used to symbolize the end of a chapter called?

Tags: manga-production, terminology

What do they call this bar? Is there official terminology for it?  Sometimes they add filler text to explain the predicament the heroes are in inside of it or surrounding it.   It also somewhat seems like a stamp to me.

Examples:

One Piece

[image]

Bleach

[image]

Toriko

[image]

Comment: Since the chapters are usually published in magazine format where many (20+) series are bundled together, and the beginning of the chapter does not necessarily start with the logo, it's something like a visual indicator to indicate the end of the chapter. Not sure how it's called, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, I know, I was just looking to find an official name for it

Comment: I don't believe there is one I've seen them referred generically as 左下隅 (bottom left corner) and/or 四角の囲 (four-cornered enclosure). The reason it's placed there is because that's where your eyes end when going through the panels on a page (right -> left, top -> bottom)

Comment: I'd like to add that all of the examples (*One Piece*, *Bleach*, and *Toriko*) are serialized in *Shonen Jump* magazine. Looking at [this reference in Japanese](https://soorce.hatenablog.com/entries/2012/03/21), while it's not on the same place, it just looks like "the indicator for the series' title". I'm not sure if there's an official name for it...